# Использование php на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Только начинаю изучение веба, а именно php, все что выдает гугл это "Создание сайта на php + mysql". Вопрос следующий - это единственный способ использования php на сайте (в перемешку с html)? просто читал что php - серверный язык.
Можно ли его вызывать отдельным файлом? И стоит ли?
Если да - можете скинуть сайты где изучали php (если изучали)

Comment: Ну а как вы отобразите в браузере содержимое без хтмл? Конемно можно в отдельном файле php код писать.

Comment: @quaresma89 тоесть использование php отдельно от html невозможно?

Comment: @Vyacheslav, php связан с html только в том случае, если необходимо в результате выполнения скрипта вернуть страницу или ее фрагмент. Советую избегать практики написания php и html кода в одном файле.

Comment: Возможно конечно,в большинстве случаев вам понадобится на основе каких то данных срендерить табличку либо еще чего,тут и будете встраивать Php  в HTML

Comment: @kover-samolet наконецто ответ на мой вопрос, тоесть я могу вызывать отдельный файл php для выполнения действия на сервере с файла html (js)?

Comment: Если вы используете PHP можете забыть про файлы с расширением HTML,весь код который вы будете писать будет находиться в основном в php файле.

Comment: @Vyacheslav, из js файла Вы можете вызвать php скрипт ajax запросом (про них лучше почитать несколько позже, если только начинаете знакомиться с вопросом). В HTML файле скрипт может быть указан только как обработчик формы, но HTML в целом - язык разметки, но не программирования, а значит и вызывать скрипты он не может.

Comment: @kover-samolet спасибо большое, именно использование в одном файле с html меня и беспокоило, так как привык уже писать .html )

Comment: Начинайте писать сразу на фреймворке! Тяжелее, но профит больше. У нас например в стране популярен Yii2 . Мой же голос за Zend3 .

Comment: А мой голос за Joomla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли его вызывать отдельным файлом?

Да, можно. Например, в консоли:

```
> php myScript.php
```

Если при этом внутри myScript.php написать что-то вроде `<?php echo 2+2;`, то в консоли ты увидишь `4`.

> И стоит ли?

Стоит, если тебе, например, нужно консольное приложение. Это обычная практика - делать такие скрипты и запускать их консольно. На практике на сайте такой скрипт может запускаться по расписанию и делать какие-то отложенные задачи для сайта по ночам: рассылать почту, подбивать кассу, считать статистику и т.д.

Если же задача запустить такой скрипт консольно, а потом открыть результат его работы в браузере, то это тоже возможно с помощью встроенного в php сервера: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php

Но не используйте его для создания полноценных сайтов. Он придуман для отладки и небольших задач.

> Если да - можете скинуть сайты где изучали php (если изучали)

Официальная документация на русском вполне годится для изучения и основ и более сложных вещей под капотом http://php.net/manual/ru/

Да, она не учит созданию сайтов с нуля, но это отдельная история и для этого не обязательно изучать именно php.

Answer (score 1):

PHP - серверный язык, а значит для работы с ним необходим сервер. Просто так открыть файл в браузере и увидеть результат нельзя. Если Вы используете Windows, то самый простой вариант для Вас - Openserver. Простая в использовании утилита, на старте не нужно тратить много времени на то, чтобы разобраться как им пользоваться. Если у Вас Linux, то стандартный LAMP сервер также отлично подойдет для начала.

Сам язык можно начать изучать здесь: 
https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php. О взаимодействии с базами данных можно почитать и в официальной документации http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php Но сначала лучше пройти курс по языку.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, давайте сперва разберемся что такое html и что такое php.
    *html - это гипертекст, разметка, визуальное представление, то что видит конечный пользователь. Это декларативный язык разметки. (почитайте о декларативных и императивных языках)
    *php - это гипертекстовый препроцессор, тоесть в каком то смысле логика поведения вашей html разметки. 
С помощью php ваш сайт сможет как то взаимодействовать с пользователем на стороне сервера, например самое банальное выводить какую то информацию из БД(базы данных).
    *Теперь собственно о php + mySql. Конечно это не единственный способ использования php. С его помощью можно создавать полнофункциональные клиент-серверные приложения, но в большинстве случаев вы будете использовать БД для структурирования ваших данных неважно сайт это или приложение, по этому php +mySql самый распространенный случай использования php.
    *Можно ли его вызывать отдельным файлом? Конечно можно, конечно нужно. Отделение логики от представления это хороший тон, отделяя ваш php код от html вам потом будет легче поддерживать ваш код, дополнять его чем то. И главное вы сможете легко менять внешний вид вашего сайта не нарушая функциональность(почитайте также о MVC (шаблон проектирования)).
*Чтобы подключить php скрипт к html документу  с расширением '.html' используйте  код:
 `<!--#include virtual='script.php' -->`
*Чтобы подключить php скрипт к html документу  с расширением последнего '.php' пишите так:

```
<?php include("script.php"); ?>
```